# How to integrate python code with C# in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, c#, google-colaboratory

Python code, which is executed on Google Colab and downloaded in .py file how to integrate it with C# code in Visual Studio 2019. On button click, Python code should execute in background and output should be displayed on WPF application.

Comment: I have no experience with but there is an integration to run Python scripts on .Net Runtime, see https://ironpython.net/

Answer (score 1):

Python code can be executed in c# by **IronPython library** and via **command prompt**. In IronPython I feel some issues. So, I will suggest you to make a process and execute it by cmd. Here is the code to do so.

````
 ```Process proc = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            info.Arguments = "/C python code.py \""+arguments+"\""; 
            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            string line = "";
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                line += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

            }```
````

But you have to install all the libraries in PC first which must be overall in the PC not only in some folder.